# How do I delete all instances of a iterable class in python?

Tags: python, class, iterable, instances, code-cleanup

I have created this form of a simple iterable class, this specific example I have found on stackoverflow. After creating the instances of the class and iterating several times over it and calling functions. I aim to cleanup the complete class and remove all instances, in addition I want to reset the _registry to an empty list. Thank you for your kind and patient help, I am an absolute newbie to Python OOP.

```
class Person(object):
    _registry = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._registry.append(self)
        self.name = name

for p in Person._registry:
    print p
```

Comment: Ok, I found a hack which does work but I am not sure that is actually good coding practice. Since my class is in an external script, it is possibe  to use reload(pythonModule_withClass)  and then reimport the person class. What is your opinion?

Comment: Is the idea that `Person` has a number of contacts or connections stored in his/her `_registry` or should the class instead be called `Registry` and hold a number of unconnected `Person` instances? Just trying to understand the structural/philosophical intention here.

Comment: I wouldn't utilize reimport. What do you mean by cleaning up the class? The registry could be cleared by `Person._registry = []`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Python caches imports and doesn't "reset" anything on re-import. I could be wrong but I remember reading something to that effect on SO the other day. As @TamasHegedus suggests, if you simply want to clear a list, redefine it as an empty list and let the automatic garbage collector take care of cleaning memory in the background. It can also be called directly via `gc` but that's rarely necessary.

Comment: Reloading the python module script that contains class works at least in my context, however the solution suggested by @Tamas Hegedus is of course better. Thank you! Besides also the the explanation that the automatic garbage collector take care of cleaning memory helped me for understanding,